# Material-UI ListItem as Link Component Changes URL but Not Rendering Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, navbar, url-routing

This is my first time asking a question here, but I am truly stumped.

I'm coding a navbar for my school project website. I'm using Material-UI's List component within the Appbar component. There are two issues I'm seeing: 1) the initial onClick will cause the route to path to '/' and 2) the second onClick will change to the proper route, but not render the desired component. Please see a gif of the issue at the bottom if it helps.

I have been working at this for a few days now, and I am not sure what I am missing

Here is my code for the List component:
`PageList.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
import { List, ListItem, ListItemText, ListItemIcon } from "@material-ui/core";
import { PAGES, usePageStatus } from "constants/pages";

const PageItem = ({ page }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { label, route, icon } = usePageStatus(page);
  return (
    <ListItem button component={Link} to={route}>
      <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={label} />
    </ListItem>
  );
};

const PageList = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 600px)", {
    noSsr: true,
  });

  return (
    <List className={clsx(isMobile ? classes.mobileList : classes.list)}>
      {PAGES.map((page) => (
        <PageItem page={page} key={page} />
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};

export default PageList;
```

Here is my code for where I use the PageList component: `TopNav.jsx`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  IconButton,
  Drawer,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import PageList from "./PageList";
import MobileTopMenu from './MobileTopMenu'

const TopNav = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 600px)", {
    noSsr: true,
  });

  return (
    <AppBar position="static" elevation={0} className={classes.appBar}>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography component="a" href="/" className={classes.title}>
          Amber+
        </Typography>
        {isMobile ? <MobileTopMenu /> : <PageList />}
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
```

Here is where I placed my nav bar and my routing code: `routes.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Router, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Home, Missing, Found, Search } from "pages";
import { PAGE_ROUTES, HOME, MISSING, FOUND, SEARCH } from "constants/pages";
import TopNav from "components/common/Nav/TopNav";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <TopNav />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={PAGE_ROUTES[HOME]} component={Home} />
        <Route exact path={PAGE_ROUTES[MISSING]} component={Missing} />
        <Route exact path={PAGE_ROUTES[FOUND]} component={Found} />
        <Route exact path={PAGE_ROUTES[SEARCH]} component={Search} />
        <Route path="*">
          <Redirect to={PAGE_ROUTES[HOME]} component={Home} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

And this is my code for my page constants: `pages.js`

```
export const HOME = "Home";
export const MISSING = "Missing";
export const FOUND = "Found";
export const SEARCH = "Search";

export const PAGES = [HOME, MISSING, FOUND, SEARCH];

export const PAGE_ROUTES = {
  [HOME]: "/",
  [MISSING]: "/missing",
  [FOUND]: "/found",
  [SEARCH]: "/search",
};

export const PAGE_ICONS = {
  [HOME]: <HomeOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />,
  [MISSING]: <FavoriteBorderIcon fontSize="small" />,
  [FOUND]: <ErrorOutlineIcon fontSize="small" />,
  [SEARCH]: <SearchIcon fontSize="small" />,
};

export const usePageStatus = (page) => {
  const route = PAGE_ROUTES[page];
  const icon = PAGE_ICONS[page];
  const label = page;

  return { route, icon, label };
};
```

Here is a gif of what I am seeing:
[image: Navbar bug]

Comment: I assume `Router` is actually a router and not `BrowserRouter as Router`? I seem to recall passing a history object to a browser router will break it since it's already using the HTML5 history API.

Comment: @lawrence-witt yes. my import is as follows: `import { Route, Router, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: How is your PAGE_ROUTES const being supplied to the Router component? Via import?

Comment: @OBN i updated the post to include my import statements.

Comment: In PageList.jsx you have not imported the Link component, does this make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Try this on `PageList.jsx`

```
import React, {useCallback} from "react";
    import clsx from "clsx";
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
    import { List, ListItem, ListItemText, ListItemIcon } from "@material-ui/core";
    import { PAGES, usePageStatus } from "constants/pages";
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const PageItem = ({ page }) => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const { label, route, icon } = usePageStatus(page);
      const history = useHistory();
      const goto = useCallback((path) => history.push(path), [history]);
      return (
        <ListItem button onClick={() => goto(route)}>
          <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={label} />
        </ListItem>
      );
    };
    
    const PageList = () => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const isMobile = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 600px)", {
        noSsr: true,
      });
    
      return (
        <List className={clsx(isMobile ? classes.mobileList : classes.list)}>
          {PAGES.map((page) => (
            <PageItem page={page} key={page} />
          ))}
        </List>
      );
```